# The constructor is undefined while creating singleton instance

Tags: java

Am having one parameterized constructor in my class `ProductDao` and i have to create singleton instance, which am not able to create it.

Its throwing "The constructor ProductDao() is undefined" error.

Please find my code below.

```
private static ProductDao instance = new ProductDao();

public static ProductDao getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public ProductDao( ObjectMapper objectMapper, RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    this.restHighLevelClient = restHighLevelClient;
}
```

Comment: Well ... What do you think that error mens? You simply don't have that constructor, but you are trying to call it.

Comment: Your only available constructor takes two arguments: `ObjectMapper` and `RestHighLevelClient`. Without a zero-parameter constructor you're unable to create an instance without passing those two required values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors. However it  doesn't provide any default constructor when you specify one. In your case, you have one.

```
public ProductDao( ObjectMapper objectMapper, RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    this.restHighLevelClient = restHighLevelClient;
}
```

You need to provide a default constructor

```
    public ProductDao() {
            // If you have default singleton beans for your mapper and client. 
//Use it to call the parameterized constructor.

        }
```

Comment: I need one instance for `ProductDao` which i have to use from another class.

Comment: Then add a default constructor of your own

Comment: @Karthikeyan  Probably your question should have been different

Comment: Public constructors violate the Singleton Pattern, but working code is working code, I guess…

Comment: @deHaar Yeah they do. You are right,, My answer is not about the best singleton practices but the cause of the error :)

Comment: @YatiSawhney you made the questioner happy, so your answer is totally ok. I just wanted to mention it near the answer marked as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want empty constructor write it additional to your constructor:

```
public ProductDao( ) {
    this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper;
    this.restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient;
}

public ProductDao( ObjectMapper objectMapper, RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    this.restHighLevelClient = restHighLevelClient;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the missing constructor, make it `private` as well as the overloaded one and implement the corresponding `getInstance` methods to have a real singleton. If you make your constructors public, you will most likely get several instances running around your JVM!

```
class ProductDao {
    private static ProductDao instance;

    public static ProductDao getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ProductDao();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // this is the parametrized getInstance method
    public static ProductDao getInstance(ObjectMapper objectMapper, RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ProductDao(objectMapper, restHighLevelClient);
        } else {
            instance.objectMapper = objectMapper;
            instance.restHighLevelClient = restHighLevelClient;
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    // this is what you need
    private ProductDao() {}

    // this has to be private
    private ProductDao( ObjectMapper objectMapper, RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.restHighLevelClient = restHighLevelClient;
    }
}
```